# An import error when using Py2app

Tags: python, py2app

I'm using py2app to pack up my python script as an .app document on mac but find an import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/py2applet", line 7, in <module>
from py2app.script_py2applet import main
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2app/script_py2applet.py", line 13, in <module>
from plistlib import Plist
ImportError: cannot import name 'Plist' from 'plistlib' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/plistlib.py)
```

And I am try to search this kind of error through google found out no one has ask the same question as mine. Is there any error with my own setting?

Answer (score 6):

This is a temporary fix until the new update is released, some time later this month.

Find path to the `py2app` directory as you will need to change some lines of code in a few files in this directory.

If you have terminal you can find the directory with:

```
find ~/ -type f -name “*py2app*”
```

> FILE 1

py2app/build_app.py
(line 614)

Replace:

```
if isinstance(self.plist, plistlib.Dict):

    self.plist = dict(self.plist.__dict__)

else:

  self.plist = dict(self.plist)
```

With the following:

```
if not isinstance(self.plist, dict):

    self.plist = dict(self.plist)
```

> FILE 2

py2app/create_appbundle.py 
(line 26)

Replace:

```
dirs = [contents, resources, platdir]

plist = plistlib.Plist()

plist.update(kw)

plistPath = os.path.join(contents, 'Info.plist')

if os.path.exists(plistPath):

    if plist != plistlib.Plist.fromFile(plistPath):

        for d in dirs:

            shutil.rmtree(d, ignore_errors=True)

for d in dirs:

    makedirs(d)

plist.write(plistPath)
```

With the following:

```
dirs = [contents, resources, platdir]

plistPath = os.path.join(contents, 'Info.plist')

if os.path.exists(plistPath):

    for d in dirs:

        shutil.rmtree(d, ignore_errors=True)

for d in dirs:

    makedirs(d)

plistlib.writePlist(kw, plistPath)
```

> FILE 3

py2app/script_py2applet.py
(line 13)

Replace:

```
from plistlib import Plist
```

With the following:

```
import plistlib
```

Also, replace (line 115)

```
plist = Plist.fromFile(fn)
```

With the following:

```
plist = plistlib.fromFile(fn)
```

Then you can finally create the setup.py file in your app directory with:

```
py2applet --make-setup my_project.py
```

And build the standalone app with:

```
python setup.py py2app -A
```

Contribution to [this guy](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issues/242/py2app-incompatible-with-new-python-37#comment-46869960) for most of the code above.

The reason for this issue is due to Plist being depreciated in python3.7. [See python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! A year went by and this is still not fixed in the upstream?