# Why py2app log me out?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, py2app

I have made an app with **py2app** *for* **MacOS (Mojave)** with **python 3.7**.

For make the app I'm using this command `python3 setup.py py2app -A`
when I open the app, it closes and log me out of the account every time.

I tried using different version of py2app from **0.14** to **0.19** but I have the same issue.

**0.13** version or less had problems on imports. 
I also tried with **0.12** version modifying the files of py2app library for avoiding [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471259/an-import-error-when-using-py2app), but I have the same problem

setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['MyApplication.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Myapplication.py

```py
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Sandwich")
    tk.Button(root, text="My first App").pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: what error does it give you?

Comment: The app log me out I can't see the error. Even with ptb trace I can't get the error, because when the app load tkinter after the `if __name__ ...` I'm logout.

Comment: Run the app from your terminal `./dist/MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication`, it ought to give you an error. Without the error, the problem is difficult to trace.

Comment: `-> root.title("Sandwich")
(Pdb) 2019-08-31 15:22:05.538 MyApplication[2933:6227251] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-31 15:22:05.538 MyApplication[2933:6227251] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459` this is the error but I saw it only before I login again.

Comment: you should have `root.mainloop()` not `tk.mainloop()`

Comment: that's not the problem, I have the same issue...

Comment: You are not alone on this, check out this thread https://bugs.python.org/issue37833 . I'll recommend you use another freezing tool like pyinstaller if the script works normally when run directly. Maybe py2app just isn't compatible with your environment setup.