# Value error '/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.7.dylib' does not exist?

Tags: python, macos, py2app, miniconda, python-standalone

so I've created a virtual environment in my iterm2 window. [this is the ques I asked earlier which has not been solved yet and my app is not running is alias mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62733188/im-trying-to-build-an-stand-alone-application-of-my-python-code-by-using-py2app)so i tried to do the whole process again but it was showing error with plistlib so that was fixed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471259/an-import-error-when-using-py2app?answertab=votes#tab-top) I tried this whole process again which means I did this all  this before but my app was not working so i deleted my py2app and some venv's got deleted to I downloaded miniconda3 again and then it was working until it comes to running the app even in alias mode . but  I continued and deleted the dist and build and when I executed
`python setup.py py2app`  but then i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
setup_requires=['py2app'],
File "/Users/divyabansal/divya/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 
145, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
File "/Users/divyabansal/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "/Users/divyabansal/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in 
run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/Users/divyabansal/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in 
run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/Users/divyabansal/divya/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 756, 
in run
self._run()
File "/Users/divyabansal/divya/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 966, 
in _run
self.run_normal()
File "/Users/divyabansal/divya/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1074, 
in run_normal
self.create_binaries(py_files, pkgdirs, extensions, loader_files)
File "/Users/divyabansal/divya/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1384, 
in create_binaries
mm.mm.run_file(runtime)
File "/Users/divyabansal/divya/lib/python3.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 89, 
in run_file
raise ValueError("%r does not exist" % (pathname,))
ValueError: '/Users/divyabansal/miniconda3/lib/libpython3.7.dylib' 
does not exist
```

please help me with this problem
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can often be fixed by creating a `symlink`, see [here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbe) for more.

```
ln -s /path/to/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib /path/to/lib/libpython3.7.dylib
```

For the above command replace it with your own path.

Comment: so i have to link my setup.py and py2app folder? because i linked by miniconda3/lib/python3.7 folder to the folder which has my setup.py and python code